# Wvdial doesn't closes properly when I call kill() function in my C code

Tags: c, ipc, kill

I have to close a wvdial connection from my C code but it doesn't close correctly: while wvdial closes, pppd process remains active and so the connection.
I create a parallel process with fork that open the wvdial connection. The code is the following (the `gsm_transmission_thread` is reduced to essentials):

```
int launch_gsm_dialer(void)
{
  pid_t child_pid;
  char *arg_list[] = {"sudo", "wvdial", "Defaults", NULL};

  child_pid = fork();
  if(child_pid != 0)
    {
      return child_pid;
    }
  else
    {
      execvp("sudo", arg_list);
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: execvp() fault in %s\n", __func__);
      return;
    }
}

void* gsm_transmission_thread(void *arg)
{
  pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE,NULL);
  pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);

  pid_t dialer_pid;

  dialer_pid = launch_gsm_dialer();

  [open protocols connection code]

  while(gsm_transmission == GSM_OPEN)
    {
      [data transmit code]
    }

  kill(dialer_pid, SIGINT);  //Here I want to close wvdial
  transmission_thread_fl = THREAD_STOP;
}
```

This code closes the wvdial process but not the pppd process. If I do ctrl^c it closes the wvdial and the pppd properly, but my program terminate in the wrong mode.
Even if I launch the `kill -2 pid` command in another terminal (I'm using Raspbian on the Raspberry), where the `pid` is the same of `dialer_pid` in the `gsm_transmission_thread()` function, the wvdial close properly its process and the pppd process.
Where I'm wrong?